# Gender of the customer who made a particular order in magento

Tags: magento2, magento-1.7, database

I want the **SQL** or the **table relationships** to find out the gender of the customer who made a particular order in magento.

Answer (score 1):

Try for Magento2

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderid);
$gender = $order->getGender();
```